# Django not storing data exactly as entered in form

Tags: django, forms

I'm Django 3.1.4 with Postgres 13

Model:

```
class Programme(models.Model):
    client = models.CharField(max_length=50, editable=True, blank=False, null=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, editable=True, blank=False, null=False)
```

View:

```
class ProgrammeCreateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Programme
        fields = ('client', 'name')
```

If the form input for 'client' is "ABC COMPANY" or "ABC Company", this data is being stored in the database as "Abc Company". Why is this and what should I be doing to ensure that the data is stored exactly as entered? Thanks.

Comment: How do you *retrieve* the data?

Comment: CharField will save "ABC COMPANY" as "ABC COMPANY". You can check it in your admin.

Comment: Whether through admin or though a generic view (listview, detailview), the result is Title Case. What I find odd is that charfields where the choices are "OPEN" or "CLOSED" are saved correctly.